# Windows 7; USB HID mouse movement delay

Tags: windows-7, usb, hid

Due to a spinal cord injury, my daughter uses alternative input access for her computers. It is a HID USB compliant device with audio feedback. It emulates both keyboard and mouse. It works well in Windows XP SP3, but in Windows 7 x 32 there is a constant half-second delay of the movement of the mouse cursor after the audio feedback confirming the command. The cursor stops the movement immediately without the delay when the audio feedback confirms the command.

The HID is operated by two switches. The switches emulate Morse code input. Inputs are decoded and sent via USB. The HID works either in the keyboard mode, or in the mouse mode. The mouse mode uses "mouse keys codes" to operate.  Both input modes are set by input codes and have to be switched.

Is there any way to shorten the delay before the cursor starts to move?

Answer (score 0):

You can try raising the USB polling rate in Windows 7; it used to be just a registry hack but in later versions of Windows (7 included), [it's a bit more involved](http://www.ngohq.com/news/15043-how-to-increase-usb-sample-rate-in-windows-vista-7-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a glitch and/or case of ‘Artificial Unintelligence’ on the part of auto-configurations attempted to say “oh, I know what you need, let me do that for you” and having little idea.

You can try manually configuring the HID hardware by doing the following:

1. Create a ‘Restore Point’ to revert back to and restore the Windows Registry if things turn bad. To do that:

   - press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>, or right click on ‘Computer’ and select ‘Properties’ (this will open the ‘System Properties’ window).
   - Select ‘System Protection’ (top-left menu) and then ‘Create’ (Restore Point). (You may need to wait a few seconds for the ‘Create’ button to become enabled.)
   - Give it a name like ‘BeforeHIDdriverTweak’. Follow the instructions.
2. Tweak the HID Driver as follows:

   - open ‘Control Panel’ (press <kbd>Win</kbd> and select ‘Control Panel’ on the right menu).
   - Open ‘Devices and Printers’ settings and right-click your HID device (should be listed; if not, you have other issues) and select ‘Properties’.
   - Select the ‘Hardware’ tab, then within the ‘Device Functions List’, select ‘HID-compliant mouse’ and click ‘Properties’.
   - Now in the ‘Properties’ box select the ‘Details’ tab and under ‘Properties’ drop-down select ‘Hardware IDs’.
   - This will now list ‘Function Value’ for the device and for starters; just select one already highlighted and confirm OK and then select OK again to exit the Device Properties.
   - Now test the device functionality.
   - In most cases this will resolve the issue but if not, redo the steps for #2 and then one-at-a-time, select each of the ‘Function Values’ for the device under ‘Hardware IDs’ for the ‘HID-compliant mouse’, then OK and OK again to exit and re-testing each time.
   - I only mention this for the 'HID-compliant mouse’ as this was the issue you had commented on.
3. Lastly – This may also be some kind of ‘wait-state’ issue between the audio confirm trigger and the mouse/keyboard device driver (or its resources) and you may also wish to check if an 'audio response' component is listed and attempting alternative 'function values' for it.

I really do hope this is of some help in resolving the issue.